# How to adjust CSS to make footer fixed height?

Tags: html, css

I have tried making every div 75px and the table within the div but only get the white background to become 75px nothing else! Whereas I want the text and images within the table in the footer and the footer itself (as a whole) to be 75px high.

HTML:

```
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">           
<div id="supplementary" class="one">
<div id="first" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
<aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
<div class="textwidget"><div id="footerwidget">
<table cellspacing="0px">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="http://www.poltairhomes.com/images/footerlogo.png" />
</td>
<td id="footertext"><p>Poltair Homes Plc<br />Registered Office: The Old Chapel, Greenbottom, Truro, Cornwall, TR4 8QP.<br />Registered in England & Wales: 3955425<br />www.poltairhomes.com<br />info@poltairhomes.com</p>
</td>
<td id="footertext"><p>Terms and Conditions | Privacy Policy | Sitemap</p>
</td>
<td id="footertext"><p>SIGN UP FOR OUR NEWSLETTER:</p><img src="http://www.poltairhomes.com/images/signup(temp).png" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></div>
</aside></div><!-- #first .widget-area -->
</div><!-- #supplementary -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#footerwidget{
background-colour: #FFF;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#footertext {
margin: 0;
padding:0 5px 0 5px;
color: #AAA;
font-size: 10px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#colophon {
clear: both;
background-colour: #FFF;
}
#supplementary {
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 0;
}
.widget-area {
font-size: 12px;
background-colour: #FFF;
}
.widget {
background-colour: #FFF;
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Any help MUCH appreciated!

Site: http://www.poltairhomes.com/

Comment: Paste a concise example of the relevant structure, and what you have tried. Otherwise this question will be a dead end as soon as you've implemented something on that external site. With the problem *and* its solution on SO, future people can benefit. Also, remove the URL from the question.

Comment: I think you should look into building websites without tables. Also, why is your footer contained within all this: `footer > div > div > aside > div > div > table > tbody > tr` That is just a hellish mess of code. Sort that out first I think!

Comment: @bigtoothmedia: You wouldn't go arrrrghhhh right now if the base template were a bit better. It's terrible, terrible mess of HTML as will said. That's the main reason you can't do much with it.

Comment: 1. please post the relevant code into your question 2. take the fuzz out of your question and replace it with precise information 3. you definitely need to restructure your code - I guess you could throw away 50% of your markup and still achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all - it's wordpress what can I say! It what happens when people try to write software that writes code for you... but it's what the client wants so... I didn't post the code because as you say it's very bulky but I will now. bear with...

Comment: The code you posted is fine. I create http://jsfiddle.net/daGcq/ and it show properly.

Comment: I've implemented the Answer (below) from Khaled and and it looks right now... Big thanks to him! I'm now going to ask how I can achieve the same footer content without tables as suggested. Thanks again all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first replace id by class

```
<td class="footertext">
```

second add vertical-align to your css

```
.footertext {
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Khaled... you are like some sort of hero!